# How to add Cache-control header to $resource in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bypass aggressive IE10 caching by setting Cache-control header to some of my GET requests.

However, it does not seem to have a desired effect. Below you can find the code I use. Names are sanitised a bit.

```
service.factory('service', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource(url + '/:year', {year : '@year'},
            {'GET': {
                headers : {
                    'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0, no-cache' }
            }});
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe suggested solutions did not help me, but give food for thought. Posting for posterity the config that eventually solved my problem.

```
var config = {
            headers : {
                "Pragma": "no-cache",
                "Expires": -1,
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

I have put the cache control inside my config.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Expires'] = '0';
```

with this, I was able to cache for IE but I had put in module config before config router provider.

---

Updated

may be something like this, I am not totally sure about it. So you can try.

```
service.factory('service', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource(url + '/:year', {year : '@year'},
            {'GET': {
                headers : {
                    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
                    'Pragma' : 'no-cache',
                    'Expires' : '0'
                }
            }});
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but it would affect all GET requests, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
service.factory('service', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource(url + '/:year', {year : '@year'},
            {'GET': {
                headers : {
                    "Pragma": "no-cache",
                    "Expires": -1,
                    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
                }
            }});
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get("your api url", {
    headers: {
        'If-Modified-Since': '0',
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Expires": -1,
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    }
})
```

This one will disable cache for every browsers.